# Easiest way to get an error message as a string in Instaparse?

Tags: clojure, instaparse

[Instaparse](https://github.com/Engelberg/instaparse) can pprint nice error messages to the REPL

```
=> (negative-lookahead-example "abaaaab")
Parse error at line 1, column 1:
abaaaab
^
Expected:
NOT "ab"
```

but I can not find a built-in function to get the message as a String. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always wrap it using `with-out-str`:

```
(with-out-str 
  (negative-lookahead-example "abaaaab"))
```

You may also be interested in using `with-err-str` [documented here](https://cloojure.github.io/doc/tupelo/tupelo.core.html#var-with-err-str).

```
(with-err-str 
  (negative-lookahead-example "abaaaab"))
```

I can't remember if `instaparse` writes to stdout or stderr, but one of those will do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the return type of `parse` in the failure case:

```
(p/parse (p/parser "S = 'x'") "y")
=> Parse error at line 1, column 1:
y
^
Expected:
"x" (followed by end-of-string)

(class *1)
=> instaparse.gll.Failure
```

This pretty printing behavior is defined like this in Instaparse:

```
(defrecord Failure [index reason])  
(defmethod clojure.core/print-method Failure [x writer]
  (binding [*out* writer]
    (fail/pprint-failure x)))
```

In the REPL this prints as a helpful human-readable description, but it can also be treated as a map:

```
(keys (p/parse (p/parser "S = 'x'") "y"))
=> (:index :reason :line :column :text)
(:reason (p/parse (p/parser "S = 'x'") "y"))
=> [{:tag :string, :expecting "x", :full true}]
```

And you could do this:

```
(with-out-str
  (instaparse.failure/pprint-failure
    (p/parse (p/parser "S = 'x'") "y")))
=> "Parse error at line 1, column 1:\ny\n^\nExpected:\n\"x\" (followed by end-of-string)\n"
```

Or write your own version of `pprint-failure` that builds a string instead of printing it.